# No inserta correctamente campo tipo Date en BD

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, excel

Realizo un modulo de importación masiva de un archivo de excel.csv pero en mi campo de fecha (DATE) no inserta correctamente los datos, solo inserta `0000-00-00`, los demás campos en la importación lo hace sin problema solo es en el campo fecha.

Gracias / Saludos

Adjunto un ejemplo de las lineas que se insertan en el archivo de excel.csv

```
7;01/12/2017;5:46:00;;;
7;01/12/2017;15:02:00;;;
10;26/11/2017;22:37:00;;;
10;27/11/2017;5:59:00;;;
```

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {//nos permite recepcionar una variable que si exista y que no sea null
    require_once("conexion_excel.php");
    require_once("functions.php");

    $archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
    $archivo_copiado= $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $archivo_guardado = "copia_".$archivo;

    //echo $archivo."esta en la ruta temporal: " .$archivo_copiado;

    if (copy($archivo_copiado ,$archivo_guardado )) {
        //echo "se copeo correctamente el archivo temporal a nuestra carpeta de trabajo <br/>";
    }else{
        //echo "hubo un error <br/>";
    }

    if (file_exists($archivo_guardado)) {

         $fp = fopen($archivo_guardado,"r");//abrir un archivo
         $rows = 0;
         while ($datos = fgetcsv($fp , 1000 , ";")) {
                $rows ++;
               // echo $datos[0] ." ".$datos[1] ." ".$datos[2]." ".$datos[3] ."<br/>";
            if ($rows > 1) {
                $resultado = insertar_datos($datos[0],$datos[1],$datos[2]);
            if($resultado){
                //echo "se inserto los datos correctamente<br/>";
            }else{
                //echo "no se inserto <br/>";
            }
            }
         }



    }else{
        echo "No existe el archivo copiado <br/>";
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Hola! ¿Podrías copiar acá un par de líneas de los datos del CSV? (Te sugiero no lo abras desde Excel, sino con el block de notas, para que sepamos qué sale realmente en la columna de la fecha que dices se inserta erróneamente). Recuerda que el formato de fecha para SQL debe ser siempre "año-mes-día" (yyyymmdd).

Comment: @quinqui Disculpa la demora en contestar pero te adjunto el ejemplo de las lineas que me indicas.                                                                                          7;01/12/2017;5:46:00;;;
7;01/12/2017;15:02:00;;;
10;26/11/2017;22:37:00;;;
10;27/11/2017;5:59:00;;;

Comment: El primer campo corresponde a mi id_Control,fecha, hora

Comment: @quinqui Esrimado ya inserte los registros de mi archivo de excel.csv que me indicaste

Comment: parece cosa del formato de fecha que utilizas en el archivo csv, que es distinto al que se tiene que utilizar al insertar en bbdd (deberia ser año-mes-dia). Revisa tu funcion insertar_datos(), a ver si el parametro de la fecha lo puedes convertir al formato de bbdd

Comment: Exacto, como dice @Jakala, tus datos fecha están en formato dd/mm/yyyy, por lo que deberás hacer una de dos: (1) cuando crees el CSV, que la fecha quede en formato yyyy-mm-dd; ó (2) cuando lo leas desde php, le des a la fecha dicho formato. Mysql no reconoce el formato dd-mm-yyyy, por eso te inserta los ceros.